# how to get the work and educational details from facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

using access token i go user details.

```
$fb_id_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$access_token;
$fb_info_json = file_get_contents($fb_id_url);
$fb_info=json_decode($fb_info_json,true);  ------ converting to array
```

my problem is, not able to get work details because it is miti-dimensional

```
$fb_info['id'] --- fine,  id is printed

echo $fb_info['work'][0][0]; ----- error
echo $fb_info['work']       ------ printing: "Array"
echo $fb_info['work']['employer']['id'] ----- error
```

json output from facebook is;

> "work":[{"employer":{"id":"xxxxxx","name":"xxxx"},"location":{"id":"xxx","name":"xxxx"},"position":{"id":"xxxx","name":"Software
>   engineer"},"description":"Description","start_date":"1996-01"},{"employer":{"id":"106216066077126","name":"xxxx"},"position":{"id":"118197931562602","name":"Maneger"},"description":"desc"},

Comment: What about the `var_dump($fb_info)` output? Can you add it to your post please?

Comment: i got the details by using:  echo $fb_info['work'][0]['employer']['id']                                                                 thaxs.

Comment: .. and put your solution as an answer

Answer (score 1):

`echo $fb_info['work'][0]['employer']['id']`